# How to fix error Array to string conversion and display the fetched data

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, echo

I am using MYSQL and PHP on WordPress  in order to retrieve data from the database but the using 4 dropdown list that allow the user to make his selection and based on the user's selection the SQL query will retrieve all the related data .

The problem is that the system is displaying the below warning:

> Array to string conversion in

and do not retrieve anything from the database.

Note: the SQL query is correct and retrieve the required data (tested on the phpmyadmin).

Code:

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: search info
    */

    get_header();
    ?>

    <?php
    // code for submit button action
    global $wpdb;
//variables that handle the retrieved data from mysql database based on the ID of the variable in HTML (select)


if(isset($_POST['query_submit']))
{

   if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
      { 
       $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
      }
      else { $site_name=""; }

    if(isset($_POST['owner_name'])) 
     {
      $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name']; 
     } 
     else { $owner_name=""; }

     if(isset($_POST['Company_name'])) 
     {
      $company_name=$_POST['Company_name'];
     } 
     else { $company_name=""; }

    if(isset($_POST['Subcontractor_name'])) 
    { 
     $Subcontractor_name=$_POST['Subcontractor_name']; 
    }
    else { $Subcontractor_name="";}

   $site_id = ['siteID'];
//$site_id = (array)$site_id;
$equipment_type = ['equipmentTYPE'];
//$equipment_type = (array)$equipment_type;
$lat=['latitude'];
//$lat = (array)$lat;
$long=['longitude'];
//$long = (array)$long;
$height = ['height'];
//$height = (array)$height;
$owner_contact = ['ownerCONTACT'];
//$owner_contact = (array)$owner_contact;
$sub_contact = ['subcontractorCONTACT'];
//$sub_contact = (array)$sub_contact;
$sub_company =[ 'subcontractorCOMPANY'];
//$sub_company = (array)$sub_company;


//query to retrieve all  related info of the selected data from the dropdown list  
$query_submit =$wpdb->get_results ("select 

site_info.siteID,site_info.siteNAME ,site_info.equipmentTYPE,site_coordinates.latitude,site_coordinates.longitude,site_coordinates.height ,owner_info.ownerNAME,owner_info.ownerCONTACT,company_info.companyNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCOMPANY,subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCONTACT from `site_info`
LEFT JOIN `owner_info`
on site_info.ownerID = owner_info.ownerID
LEFT JOIN `company_info` 
on site_info.companyID = company_info.companyID
LEFT JOIN `subcontractor_info` 
on site_info.subcontractorID = subcontractor_info.subcontractorID
LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` 
on site_info.siteID=site_coordinates.siteID 
where 
site_info.siteNAME = `$site_name` 
AND
owner_info.ownerNAME = `$owner_name`
AND
company_info.companyNAME = `$company_name`
AND
subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME = `$Subcontractor_name`
 " , ARRAY_A);

// create a table  inside php code 

echo "<table width='30%' ";
echo     " <tr>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['siteNAME']</td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit  ['ownerNAME']</td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit  ['companyNAME']</td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['subcontractorNAME']</td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['siteID'] </td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['equipmentTYPE'] </td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['latitude'] </td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['longitude'] </td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['height']</td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['ownerCONTACT']</td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['subcontractorCONTACT']</td>";
echo         " <td>$query_submit ['subcontractorCOMPANY']</td>";
echo     "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

[image: web page after clicking the submit button]

Comment: Try to check the output using var_dump. Use the `var_dump($query_submit)` and tell me what is the output of that.

Comment: Is this correct format for calling a string `$query_submit  ['ownerNAME']` There is a space between `$query_submit` and `['ownerNAME']`

Comment: i tried var_dump($query_submit) it display **array(0) { }**  but i tried the query in phpmyadmin it return the required values

Comment: @NabilJaroush The issue is at `$site_id = ['siteID'];` Here you are using array as string as the error is here. I am not able to figure out what exactly should be there.

Comment: this field will handle multiple values based on the user selection from the 4 dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

In your echo is not correct way of calling a string you give the space between `$query_submit ['string']` Use like this `$query_submit['siteNAME']` And your query submit query has little change :

```
    <?php
        /*
        Template Name: search info
        */

        get_header();
        ?>

        <?php
        // code for submit button ation
        global $wpdb;
    //variables that handle the retrieved data from mysql database based on the ID of the variable in HTML (select)


    if(isset($_POST['query_submit']))
    {

       if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
          { 
           $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
          }
          else { $site_name=""; }

        if(isset($_POST['owner_name'])) 
         {
          $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name']; 
         } 
         else { $owner_name=""; }

         if(isset($_POST['Company_name'])) 
         {
          $company_name=$_POST['Company_name'];
         } 
         else { $company_name=""; }

        if(isset($_POST['Subcontractor_name'])) 
        { 
         $Subcontractor_name=$_POST['Subcontractor_name']; 
        }
        else { $Subcontractor_name="";}

       $site_id = $_POST['siteID'];
    //$site_id = (array)$site_id;
    $equipment_type = $_POST['equipmentTYPE'];
    //$equipment_type = (array)$equipment_type;
    $lat=$_POST['latitude'];
    //$lat = (array)$lat;
    $long=$_POST['longitude'];
    //$long = (array)$long;
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    //$height = (array)$height;
    $owner_contact = $_POST['ownerCONTACT'];
    //$owner_contact = (array)$owner_contact;
    $sub_contact = $_POST['subcontractorCONTACT'];
    //$sub_contact = (array)$sub_contact;
    $sub_company =$_POST[ 'subcontractorCOMPANY'];
    //$sub_company = (array)$sub_company;


    $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results ("select site_info.siteID,site_info.siteNAME ,site_info.equipmentTYPE,site_coordinates.latitude,site_coordinates.longitude,site_coordinates.height ,owner_info.ownerNAME,owner_info.ownerCONTACT,company_info.companyNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCOMPANY,subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCONTACT from `site_info`
    LEFT JOIN `owner_info`
    on site_info.ownerID = owner_info.ownerID
    LEFT JOIN `company_info` 
    on site_info.companyID = company_info.companyID
    LEFT JOIN `subcontractor_info` 
    on site_info.subcontractorID = subcontractor_info.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` 
    on site_info.siteID=site_coordinates.siteID 
    where 
    site_info.siteNAME = ".$site_name."
    AND
    owner_info.ownerNAME = ".$owner_name."
    AND
    company_info.companyNAME = ".$company_name."
    AND
    subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME = ".$Subcontractor_name."
     " , ARRAY_A);
    if($query_submit){
    echo "<table width='30%' ";
echo     "<tr>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->siteNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->ownerNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->companyNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->siteID."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->latitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->longitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->height."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$query_submit->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
echo     "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "query is not worked";
    }
```

Comment: @ Nawim  if i delete the space i got this error : 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)**

Comment: then you use `$query_submit->siteNAME`

Comment: Edit the answer...Check now

Comment: i tried your answer but nothing change nothing is displayed

Comment: i tried your answer it display this error : **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)**   because there is no space between  **$query_submit** and **['siteNAME']**

Comment: `echo         "<td>".$query_submit->siteNAME."</td>";` Change like this and let me know what you get and change all your `<td>` echo

Comment: for the note  **siteNAME** and other values are retrieved from 5 different tables so is it better to write **site_info.siteNAME**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136140/discussion-between-nawin-and-nabil-jaroush).

Answer (score 0):

The error come from below lines:

```
$site_id = ['siteID'];
//$site_id = (array)$site_id;
$equipment_type = ['equipmentTYPE'];
//$equipment_type = (array)$equipment_type;
$lat=['latitude'];
//$lat = (array)$lat;
$long=['longitude'];
//$long = (array)$long;
$height = ['height'];
//$height = (array)$height;
$owner_contact = ['ownerCONTACT'];
//$owner_contact = (array)$owner_contact;
$sub_contact = ['subcontractorCONTACT'];
//$sub_contact = (array)$sub_contact;
$sub_company =[ 'subcontractorCOMPANY'];
```

I am not sure that if you are getting these variables from post. If you are getting these from post values then use:

```
$site_id = $_POST['siteID'];
           ^^^use global variable
```

But as I can see that you are using it in `$query_submit` array variable. it means it is coming from db.

In that case you have to remove or comment these lines.

Comment: if i remove these lines how i will be able to display the retrieved data

Comment: You are using these lines before executing the query so there is no mean of these line. once try after removing these lines.